# how to change the button style

Tags: html, css

I want to change the style of button [image: this is my button]

to this style [image: this is the style i want]

my css code for the button is

```
#login{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: Okay...? Add some rounded edges, make it smaller, change the font, and you're done. What is the question here, if not "someone do this for me"?

Comment: #login{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 5%;
    text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

Comment: If you are aware of some CSS, it can be easily doable. The CSS you shared here is a bit complicated, and I think the default styles set in your project's stylesheet are affecting it too.

Comment: @Dev-stud how to reduce the size it still looks big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#login{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 5%;
    text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="login">login</div>
```

Comment: the button still looks big how to reduce the size

Comment: You can reduce `padding: 5px 15px` to `padding: 3px 11px` and so on.
Also you can add `font-size: 11px` property

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="login">login</div>

#login{
  display:inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px 15px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Fiddler link is https://jsfiddle.net/wu7L8ct9/2/

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use class selector to apply style to your button

```
<button class="login-btn">Login</button>
```

And you can use this styles to get the wanted result

```
.login-btn {
  font-family: sans serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

try to avoid using this css attributes in your  btn style
`width: 5%;`
`margin-left: 1000px;`
CSS styles must be encapsulated for each page component